# Convert Image URI to File or Blob

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I am able to get the image URI using Ionic [Image Picker plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/image-picker):

```
this.imagePicker.getPictures(options).then((results) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        //below logs: 'Image URI: file:///Users/josh.0/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CC0FFBD2-EADF-4489-8F22-7948E0EFD261/data/Containers/Data/Application/2BC3C571-61B7-4EFF-A4D1-4D1F99F04EBC/tmp/cdv_photo_013.jpg'
        console.log('Image URI: ' + results[i]);  
    }
}, (err) => { });
```

I need to get this image as a File, so I can upload it.  I've tried doing the following, but it doesn't work:

```
this.imagePicker.getPictures(options).then((results) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
       console.log('Image URI: ' + results[i]);
       let base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + results[i];
         fetch(base64Image)
            .then(res => res.blob())
            .then(blob => {
                //Doesnt fire
                console.log("Got blob")
                const file = new File([blob], "image.png")
         })
    }
}, (err) => { });
```

How do I convert an image URI to file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ionic really needs to improve their documentation.  The documentation on the plugin in [the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/image-picker) is absolutely pathetic.  Took me hours to figure this out on my own.  Anyway, here it is:

```
getImage() {
    const options = {
        maximumImagesCount: 1,
        width: 800,
        height: 800,
        quality: 100,
        outputType: 1 //Set output type to 1 to get base64img
    };

    this.imagePicker.getPictures(options).then((results) => {
        var files: File[] = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        console.log('Image URI: ' + results[i]);
        let blob = this.getBlob(results[i], ".jpg")
         const file = new File([blob], "image.jpg")
         //Do something with file like upload
       }
    }, (err) => { });
}



private getBlob(b64Data:string, contentType:string, sliceSize:number= 512) {
    contentType = contentType || '';
    sliceSize = sliceSize || 512;
    let byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
    let byteArrays = [];

    for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
        let slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

        let byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
        for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
            byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        let byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

        byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }
    let blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
    return blob;
}
```

Comment: How can i find the atob(b64Data) function?
It seems missing in your answer..

Comment: its part of typescript.

Comment: I get a decoding error with the `atob` function. Is this only for JPG data?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the file from the directory with AJAX. I use AngularJS and below is what I used to get the Blob. You can pretty much convert this to whatever JS framework/library you're using.

AngularJS method:

```
$http.get(file_uri, {'responseType':'blob'}).then(successMethod, failMethod);
```